# how to add Header div stays at top and vertical scrolling div below?

Tags: css, layout, header, scroll

i want to have a two divs,the header and a scrolling list contained in a div.

This is what i'm trying to achieve:

```
|_______header_______|
|                    |
|   Container Div    |
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
----------------------
```

now ,i have the scroll content div that's can scroll auto ,but how to add the header dive

```
   <div id="scroller_container">
    <div class="jscroller2_up">
    <?
    echo $news;
    ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.jscroller2_up, .jscroller2_down, .jscroller2_left, .jscroller2_right {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 }

#scroller_container {
width: 30em;
height: 8em;
background: white;
 top: -300px;
left: 700px;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Please try div.header { position: fixed; }

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: fixed`. Here I have a 4em high header with a full height content area. JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v7bd5vz9/.

HTML:

```
<header>Header</header>
<main>
    <p>main</p>
</main>
```

CSS:

```
header {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 4em;
    background: green;
}

main {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 4em;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```